# Replace backslash followed by double quotation in a text file in Python

Tags: python, regex, double-quotes, backslash

I have a text file, and its content is like this:

```
"good to know it \" so nice \" "
```

I use Python to read its contents and want to replace `"` with an empty string.

The code I am using is:

```
import re

file_path = "backslash_double_quotation.txt"
with open(file_path, "r") as input_file:
    raw_text = input_file.read()
processed_text = re.sub(r'\"', "", raw_text)
print(raw_text)
print(processed_text)
```

and I expect processed_text like this:

```
"good to know it  so nice  "
```

However, the actual output is:

```
good to know it \ so nice \
```

All the double quotations are replaced by empty strings.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `re.sub` treats `r'\"'` as a regular expression, and the regular expression `\"` only matches a literal `"` (as `"` has no special meaning in a regular expression). `r'\"'` would be correct if you using string equality, and not regular-expression matching.

Answer (score 1):

With strings you can use `.replace()` to replace specific characters or words in a string.

For example:

```
text = "good to know it \" so nice \""
print(text.replace("\"", " "))
```

The output for this is:

```
good to know it   so nice
```

With your code:

```
import re
file_path = "backslash_double_quotation.txt"
with open(file_path, "r") as input_file:
    raw_text = input_file.read()
processed_text = raw_text.replace("\"", "")
print(raw_text)
print(processed_text)
```

If you want to use `re` then:

```
processed_text = re.sub(r"\\", "", raw_text)
```

Comment: The input file contains actual backslashes, and this is still going to leave those backslashes in. We can see the backslashes aren't just a string `repr` thing - the code in the question isn't doing anything that would call `repr`, and the post-`re.sub` output contains backslashes with no quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the expected result because of "raw-string", "r" in your example. If you add "r" you should specify your regex expression without any escape characters.

Just remove "r" in your example and it will work as expected:

```
processed_text = re.sub('\"', "", raw_text)
```

Reference:

*[Raw String Notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)*

Comment: See @chepner comment above. Regex does not see `\"` as a special escape sequence so it treats it as just a quote literal `"` to match https://regex101.com/r/csMyXv/1 . The op needs to match the escape character `\\ ` plus quote `"` equals `\\"` that needs to get to rx engine.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate one by one

```
processed_text = raw_text.replace('"', '')
processed_text = processed_text.replace('\', '')
```

Comment: First, `processed_text.replace('\', '')` is invalid syntax, and second, the questioner only wants to remove backslash-and-quotation-mark sequences, not solo backslashes or solo quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine that an escaped double quote `\"` means something else than include this quote in the delimited double quote string. Therefore it's impossible to imagine not using an escaped escape `\\` to differentiate an included escape in the string from not treating a following double quote (if any) as the closing string delimiter.

This seems to be a nonambiguous way to tell the difference -

https://regex101.com/r/FH2Dfp/1

Find (*raw context, wrap in r' '*):

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\"
```

Replace with:

`\1`

Answer (score 0):

I found this works:

```
processed_text = re.sub(r'\\"', "", raw_text)
```